# I am full of Tamasic qualities

Tags: tamasic

Aside from changing diets, is there anything else that can be done? I see myself when the term tamasic person is used. I unfortunately fall into this category but unable to escape it.

Comment: imagine eating tamasik foods for 20 years - all your bones, muscles, fat, nerves are composed of it. body's cells regenerate every 7 years or so. to undo it, you have to eat satvik foods for 7 years, right ? now, imagine doing so for several lifetimes. undoing will take equal time. so don't expect immediate results. slow and steady wins the race.